# Static content missing add mime types

Tags: asp.net, iis, mime-types

I'm trying to deploy a legacy application which is written in .net framework 2.0
I have checked that .net framework 2.0 is installed and the mime type on iis already contains static content with file extension as * and mimetype as appliaction/octet-stream

When I try to browse the page, I'm getting
HTTP Error 404.17 - Not found. 
The requested content appears to be script and will not be served by the static file handler.

Answer (score 1):

On windows server, we cannot use the asp_regiis command. We had to install .net framework 3.5 which contained Framework 2.0. Ensure that application pool is using the .net clr version 2.0.
In the Application Development section - Make sure to check the ASP.NET 3.5 option